# php: How to find a string in a paragraph

Tags: php, string, variables, character

Let's say that I have:

```
$strPar = "This is a simple paragraph that we will use for the questioning";
$strFindMe = "that";
```

How will I check if `$strPar` contains `$strFindMe`?

Comment: http://php.net/strpos

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fastest way is to use [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
  $exists = strpos($strPar, $strFindMe);
  if ($exists !== false) {
    // substring is in the main string
  }
```

Comment: @BartFriederichs is it compulsory to use `!== false` !

Comment: sir another question, how can i replace a new line with "|"

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
if (false !== strpos($strPar, $strFindMe ) )
```

Comment: why do you need `false !== ` since it returns boolean value ?

Comment: it returns the position which if it's at the beginning of the string will be 0 which would evaluate to false.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "This is a strpos() test";
$pos = strpos($string, "i", 3);

    if ($pos === false) {
     print "Not found\n";
}else{
     print "Found at $pos!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$strPar = "This is a simple paragraph that we will use for the questioning";
$strFindMe   = "that";
$pos = strpos($strPar, $strFindMe);

// Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
// because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with [strpos()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strpos.asp) function, it is case sensitive!

```
if( strpos($strPar, $strFindMe) ) {  //it return a boolean value
   echo "String Found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$strPar = "This is a simple paragraph that we will use for the questioning";
$strFindMe = "THAT";//Find the position of the first occurrence of a case-insensitive substring in a string
$exists = strpos($strPar, $strFindMe);
  if ($exists !== false) {
    // substring is in the main string
  }
```